# MongoDb and Golang - Match before Group

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to **$match** my list of **Event** before to **$group** them but it does not work. If I remove the first `$match`, I get results.

The **Event** has a **start_date** property.

I need to get the IDs of the duplicated events that start from 2 months to now. A duplicated event is an event that is a the same location at same hour.

```
    // Create the pipeline
    pipeline := []bson.M{
        bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{
                "start_date": bson.M{"$gt": time.Now().AddDate(0, -2, 0)},
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$group": bson.M{
                "_id": bson.M{
                    "_location_id": "$_location_id",
                    "start_date":   "$start_date",
                },
                "docs":  bson.M{"$push": "$_id"},
                "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{
                "count": bson.M{"$gt": 1.0},
            },
        },
    }
```

Am I missing something ?

I checked in database and I do have events that have a `start_date` matching my criteria, with that request `db.events.find({}).sort({ "start_date": -1}).limit(1);` and that one `db.events.find({"start_date": { "$gt": ISODate("2019-05-16T00:00:00.0Z")}}).limit(1)`

Version : MongoDB shell version v3.4.6

Comment: Did you answer yourself already, are you sure you have data with the first match running alone?

Comment: Yes I do have data when performing this search : `db.events.find({"start_date": { "$gt": ISODate("2019-05-16T00:00:00.0Z")}}).limit(1);`

Comment: Are you sure you're querying from the `events` collection? Also `time.Now()` uses local time, and the query you claim has results uses UTC (there might be few hours difference).

Comment: @icza given that the times include time zone information, I doubt that's relevant to the issue.

Comment: @Adrian His query does not have time zone info, it contains UTC timestamp. It may make a difference if he only has matching documents that are between `2019-05-16T00:00:00.0` UTC and `time.Now() - 2 months`.

Comment: The query in Go passes a `time.Time`, which includes location information. The query quoted in the comment executed in mongo specifies UTC.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, and the time in the query has 0:00 time part, only date. If his local time is 16:00 and zone is let's say UTC+2, that translates to 14:00 UTC. So there is a 14-hour window between the 2 timestamps.

Comment: @icza : I am UTC+2 yes. But I do not get it, I am only filtering with a **FROM** value, I do not specify a **TO**. From May to know, if I remove the `$match`, I do have results... incredible !

Comment: Stupid question, does it need to be inside the same `bson.M` than the `$group` one ?

Comment: Try to use `time.Date(2019, 5, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)` instead of `time.Now()`. Does it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

> I checked in database and I do have events that have a start_date matching my criteria, with that request

[MongoDB stores time in UTC](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) by default, and will convert any local time representations into this form.

This means, if you are in `UTC+2` timezone, your query filter is by default would be in local time but the documents in the database is in UTC. You need to convert your `time` to UTC. For example, you have the following documents in a collection:

```
{ "start_date": ISODate("2019-05-27T00:00:00Z"), "location_id": 1 },
{ "start_date": ISODate("2019-05-28T00:00:00Z"), "location_id": 2 },
{ "start_date": ISODate("2019-05-24T00:00:00Z"), "location_id": 1 },
```

You can perform `$match` for dates two months ago as below:

```
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$match", bson.D{
        {"start_date", bson.D{
            {"$gt", time.Now().AddDate(0, -2, 0).UTC()},
            }, 
        },
    }}}, 
}
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
defer cursor.Close(context.Background())
for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
    var doc bson.M
    err := cursor.Decode(&doc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(doc)
}
```

Note the conversion to `UTC` after the calculation. If today is already the 24th July 2019, then the query will not matched the third document. Instead you need to query with **2 months and 1 day ago**.

Another tip is you can debug the date sent to the server by printing the `pipeline`, i.e:

```
fmt.Println(pipeline)
// [[{$match [{start_date [{$gt 2019-05-24 05:19:47.382049 +0000 UTC}]}]}]]
```

If you have a static date value, you can also construct the date (still in UTC) as below example:

```
filterDate := time.Date(2019, 5, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$match", bson.D{
        {"start_date", bson.D{
            {"$gt", filterDate},
            }, 
        },
    }}},
}
fmt.Println(pipeline)
```

All of the snippets above are written for [MongoDB Go driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) v1.0.x.